# Can I create a java object with specific methods ignored?

Tags: java, object

Consider that I have a class named `Validation` with five methods.  All the methods are very complex and large.  In a certain part of my application, I need to create a `Validation` object, but I'll only be using one method from that object.  I could make the method `static` to fulfill my purpose, but for the rest of the application to keep working, those methods should be non-static.

So is there a way that I can create an object of a class containing only one of the non-static methods?

Comment: Sounds a bit like an XY problem...

Comment: Methods are not data, they do not occupy memory or space the same way properties do, you do not have to worry about the "duplication" of methods because you create multiple objects.

Comment: You could make another class that just has that one method, with as body an identical call to a field of the original class. Is called "delegating."

Comment: @Nivas The problem isn't about duplicating the methods. I am going to use the object to call one method just once. I felt that having those other methods created will be waste of time and memory ( I know it's a negligible amount when compared to the large picture, but still... )

Comment: @Barath You will save no "memory" this way. Methods do not occupy memory. And since we are talking Java, the memory scale is different (than compared to, say, assembly) so you can safely ignore the few bytes, if any, of the additional usage. If you are curious, use [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) that is included in the JDK (1.6+) to see memory usage of your objects.

Comment: Also note that if your class is just a collection of methods that are not related to each other, you either have a design problem or a helper/utility class (which I think is your case, considering *Validation*), and helper/utility methods are generally `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

About the best you can do (to answer the question as asked) is make the method `protected` and have a subclass of `Validation` which `extends` it.  Then, if all the other methods are `private`, that object will only have the one `protected` one.

It's kind of a bad situation, though.  More than likely, if you're trying to do this, you're either trying to optimize for no reason or you have a bad design somewhere.

e.g.,

```
public class Validation {

    private void method1() {}
    private void method2() {}
    protected void method3() {}
    private void method4() {}
}
```

...

```
public class RestrictedValidation extends Validation { }
```

...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestrictedValidation validation = new RestrictedValidation();
    validation.method1(); //compiler error
    validation.method2(); //compiler error
    validation.method3(); //success
    validation.method4(); //compiler error
}
```

But yeah.  I can't think of a single valid use-case for this.

Comment: But this will only restrict the use of other methods, does not prevent the object from loading methods of class into memory ,like the way OP wants ` i can create an object of a class containing only one of the non-static methods` , and not to just hide them.

Comment: @Mustafasabir True.  Depends on the definition of "containing".

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by way of inheritance where ValidationA would contain common methods used by most clients (here your one particular method), and a ValidationB class which extends ValidationA and add more specialized methods.

Or depending of the situation, it could be 2 completely different objects.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such way. An object consist of state and related behavior. An object stores its state in fields and exposes its behavior through methods. Methods operate on an object's internal state and serve as the primary mechanism for object-to-object communication.

what you is saying is create a person object(whose has already defined behaviour of walking and running) but he should only walk and not run. It does not make sense.
Jeff Gohlke provided a good solution to it